# Firestore Structure Array Organization

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, model

This is the data I have obtained from an excel sheet and I want to create firestore documents with the same id of *kdocID* variables and populate it's content from the remaining arrays:

```
List<String> kdocID = [
  '5846', 
  '5846',
  '5845',
  '5844',
  '5845',
];

List<String> kdate = [
  '2.05.2023',
  '2.05.2023',
  '3.05.2023',
  '2.05.2023',
  '2.05.2023',
];

List<String> kuserID = [
  '600PLN03',
  '600PLN03',
  '600PZR03',
  '600PZR17',
  '600PZR03',
];
List<String> kcompanyName = [
  'Company 1',
  'Company 1',
  'Company 2',
  'Company 3',
  'Company 2',
];
List<dynamic> kcompanyID = [
  1200204792,
  1200204792,
  1204000605,
  1200200941,
  1204000605,
];
List<dynamic> kentry = [
  10,
  20,
  20,
  10,
  10,
];
List<dynamic> kentryProductID = [
  20041976,
  20041976,
  30036627,
  30053904,
  30056608,
];
List<dynamic> kentryAmount = [
  10,
  1200,
  3000,
  150,
  10000,
];
List<String> korderUnit = [
  'KG',
  'KG',
  'M',
  'M',
  'M',
];
List<dynamic> kentryCost = [
  30,
  3600,
  8190,
  8650,
  27800,
];
List<String> korderCurrency = [
  'USD',
  'USD',
  'EUR',
  'JPY',
  'EUR',
];
```

The following structure is how I need to organize my database;

[image]

How can I achieve the previously shown structure with this obtained data? I have tried the following code but the problem with this code is that the arrays won't add duplicated values such as the case with the document *5846* where the field of entryProductID it's the same value twice.

```
for (var i = 0; i < kdocID.length; i++) {

      db.collection('Orders').doc(kdocID[i]).set(
        {
          'date': Timestamp.fromDate(DateFormat('d.MM.yyyy').parse(kdate[i])),
          'userID': kuserID[i],
          'companyName': kcompanyName[i],
          'companyID': kcompanyID[i],
          'entry': FieldValue.arrayUnion([kentry[i]]),
          'entryProductID': FieldValue.arrayUnion([kentryProductID[i]]),
          'entryAmount': FieldValue.arrayUnion([kentryAmount[i]]),
          'entryCost': FieldValue.arrayUnion([kentryCost[i]]),
          'orderUnit': korderUnit[i],
          'orderCurrency': korderCurrency[i],
        },
        SetOptions(merge: true),
      );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow duplicate data in an array field, you can't use the `arrayUnion` operator to add it. By definition, that operator does not add duplicate.

There also is no `arrayAdd` operator, so the only way to add duplicates is to:

1. Read the document from the database
2. Add the element to the array in your application code
3. Write the entire array back to the database

If you expect that multiple clients may do this around the same time, be sure to [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) for the operation.

Answer (score 0):

As **Frank van Puffelen** mentioned `arrayUnion` won't solve if you want to add duplicate values. Thus, you need to add each of the elements to the array in the application and write it back to Firestore like this;

```
  _addData() {
    Map<String, Map<String, dynamic>> docIDMap = {};

    for (int i = 0; i < kdocID.length; i++) {
      String docID = kdocID[i];
      if (!docIDMap.containsKey(docID)) {
        docIDMap[docID] = {
          'date': kdate[i],
          'userID': kuserID[i],
          'companyName': kcompanyName[i],
          'companyID': kcompanyID[i],
          'entry': [kentry[i]],
          'entryProductID': [kentryProductID[i]],
          'entryAmount': [kentryAmount[i]],
          'entryCost': [kentryCost[i]],
          'orderUnit': korderUnit[i],
          'orderCurrency': korderCurrency[i],
        };
      } else {
        docIDMap[docID]?['entry'].add(kentry[i]);
        docIDMap[docID]?['entryProductID'].add(kentryProductID[i]);
        docIDMap[docID]?['entryAmount'].add(kentryAmount[i]);
        docIDMap[docID]?['entryCost'].add(kentryCost[i]);
      }
    }

    for (var docID in docIDMap.keys) {
      db.collection('Orders').doc(docID).set(docIDMap[docID]!);
    }
  }
```

Comment: It's not common on Stack Overflow to implement the approach outlined in an answer, post that as your own answer, and then accept that. :-/

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it is late answer I know but your answer doesn't have any code, I honestly didn't know how it's supposed to be.